# Sharepoint Online - REST API Authentication

Tags: authentication, sharepoint-rest-api

I have normal web application (ASP.NET MVC) and I would like to communicate with SharePoint Online (read and write to any list). 
I would like to use SharePoint REST API and I dont know how to authenticate to SharePoint. In most articles is written that I need create SharePoint Add-In. Is right way? Must I allways create Add-In when I need communicate with REST API? Can I get somewhere any access token? 
Please help me, I dont know SharePoint. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

we can use O365 Api to access O365 Mails,Contacts,Sites(SharePoint Sites),etc...  please check this link for more info [Integrate Office 365 APIs into .NET Visual Studio projects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/howto/authenticate-and-use-services).

There are so many examples available in Github for the same.  please find the some of the links below.

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-webapi-openidconnect

[O365-SharePoint-FilePush](https://github.com/dougperkes/O365-SharePoint-FilePush)

[Office-365-REST-API-Explorer](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Office-365-REST-API-Explorer)

Hope it helps.